# Make armature bend across multiple vertices

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

My file:
[image]

I'm very, very new to Blender and I'm trying to rig up a really simple low-poly character. I've got it rigged but no matter what I do, the joints are only pivoting across one vertex, even though I gave it more vertices to bend on. No matter how I adjust the weights it's not bending the way I want.

I want this armature to bend across all three of the circled vertices equally, but it's only choosing one vertex to bend along and the others stay straight, causing clipping when bent too far.

[image]

Here's how it's bending now:
[image]

Here's my weights:
[image]
[image]

I've tried painting the weights every which way but it doesn't seem to change anything at all.

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/ (remove the parts of the character that you don't want to share)

Comment: @moonboots Posted at the top. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we can see if we select one of these vertices it is assigned to several vertex groups (not sure what are the 2 firsts) but the weight of *arm.l* is much higher than the weight of *shoulder.l*, so the influence of the forearm will be much higher when you'll bend the arm:

[image]

What you could do is remove all this edge loop from any group:

[image]

Then assign it to the groups called *shoulder.l* and *arm.l* with the same *Weight* (it can be 1, as long as the weight will be the same, both the 2 bones will have the same influence):

[image]

Also maybe check the adjacent edge loop, and enable the *Preserve Volume* option of the *Armature* modifier. Result:

[image]

Also you could try some alternative topologies:

[image]

Or:

[image]

If you want the vertices of solution 1 to merge so that you get solution 2, select all these vertices, assign them to a new vertex group that you'll call *Weld* for example:

[image]

Give your object a *Weld* modifier, select the *Weld* vertex group and increase the *Distance* until the vertices merge when the arm is bent:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I actually like the new topology idea. I'm wondering now if it's possible to use a combination of those two topology suggestions. I'd like it to use the first one until those two inner edges touch, and then I want those edges to merge into one and then bend on a single edge like in your second pic. Is that possible?

Comment: See my edit and try the Weld modifier